# order definition for comparisons in SQL ROW subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, subquery, lexicographic

I was wondering when a row subquery is performed with a comparison operator such as `>` or `>=`, is the order of comparison defined using lexicographic (i.e. dictionary) order or is it defined element-wise?

That is, for `ROW (A, B)`, should

```
(79, 48) > (75, 52)
```

be `TRUE` (dictionary) or `FALSE` (element-wise) in a row query in the `WHERE` clause?

I tested this in PostgreSQL, and it seems that it's using the dictionary order, i.e. `(79, 48) > (75, 52)` is `TRUE` because `79 > 75` and the second component doesn't matter therefore. Searching around, it seems that this is also the case with MySQL: [MySQL row subquery comparison issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206527/mysql-row-subquery-comparison-issue), and the MySQL documentation seems to be confusing on this point. Searching for `postgresql row subquery` doesn't show much about the comparison order.

While the dictionary order makes sense from a computer science perspective, it may look a bit weird to a database user because the order of rows now depends on *which column you list first in the SQL*. For example, using dictionary order, we should have:

```
 (52, 75) > (48, 79)
```

for `ROW (B,A)`. The same rows are compared, the order is exactly the opposite because column `B` is listed first.

My question is:

Is this behavior (use of dictionary order in row queries) from SQL standards/cross-vendor or is it implementation specific? Any references for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the chapter [Row Constructor Comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON) of the **Postgres** manual:

> For the `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` cases, the row elements are compared
> left-to-right, stopping as soon as an unequal or null pair of elements
> is found. If either of this pair of elements is null, the result of
> the row comparison is unknown (null); otherwise comparison of this
> pair of elements determines the result. For example, `ROW(1,2,NULL) < ROW(1,3,0)` yields true, not null, because the third pair of elements
> are not considered.

And:

> Note: Prior to PostgreSQL 8.2, the `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` cases were not
> handled per SQL specification. A comparison like `ROW(a,b) < ROW(c,d)`
> was implemented as `a < c AND b < d` whereas the correct behavior is
> equivalent to `a < c OR (a = c AND b < d)`.

Which clarifies that the behavior of modern Postgres is according to the SQL standard.

It's basically the same logic as in the `ORDER BY` clause of a `SELECT` query: items are compared left to right until the first inequality is found - except for NULL values, which sort *last* in default ascending order.

Related:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)